# Appending '0x' before the hex numbers in a string

Tags: python, parsing

I'm parsing a xml file in which I get basic expressions (like `id*10+2`). What I am trying to do is to evaluate the expression to actually get the value. To do so, I use the `eval()` method which works very well.

The only thing is the numbers are in fact hexadecimal numbers. The `eval()` method could work well if every hex number was prefixed with '0x', but I could not find a way to do it, neither could I find a similar question here. How would it be done in a clean way ?

Comment: How are you going to parse `CAFE+BABE`?

Comment: Well, CAFE and BABE would be hex numbers. The only variable name I have to take care of is `Id`.
So ideally it would take `CAFE+BABE` and transform it into `0xCAFE+0xBABE`

Comment: What about expressions such as `"open('/tmp/a-file-on-your-system','w').write(\"Careful!\")"`? Have you tried `eval`ing that?

Comment: @Joe thanks for warning me, but as I commented on fortran's answer, this is just quick prototyping. It will be replaced with something safer a little later.

Comment: Of course. There are certain things which should always be pointed out (eval, SQL injection) just for the record. Maybe someone will see it that didn't know before. For example, I see plenty of questions with SQL injection vulnerabilities, so I know it's always worth saying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'([\dA-F]+)', r'0x\1', 'id*A+2')
'id*0xA+0x2'
>>> eval(re.sub(r'([\dA-F]+)', r'0x\1', 'CAFE+BABE'))
99772
```

Be warned though, with an invalid input to `eval`, it won't work. There are also [many risks](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) of using `eval`.

If your hex numbers have lowercase letters, then you could use this:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!i)([\da-fA-F]+)', r'0x\1', 'id*a+b')
'id*0xa+0xb'
```

This uses a negative lookbehind assertion to assure that the letter `i` is not before the section it is trying to convert (preventing `'id'` from turning into `'i0xd'`. Replace `i` with `I` if the variable is `Id`.

Comment: Just about to hit enter on that myself ;)

Comment: I tried this solution, but it works only for numbers lower than 'A'. As soon as there is a hex character (i.e. from 'a' to 'f') it is not replaced (\d+ does not allow letters as numbers)

Comment: In fact it works well... as long as `Id` is not part of the expression to parse ! It gets replaced by `I0xd` (I didn't see that one coming!)

Comment: Indeed I edited your code as the variable was `Id`. Thanks a lot for your quick and useful answers

Answer (score 0):

If you can parse expresion into individual numbers then I would suggest to use [int function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> int("CAFE", 16)
51966
```

Comment: That is a nice solution indeed, but the whole problem was to split the expression correctly (which is kind of hard because of the letters in hex numbers). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with `eval`! Do not ever use it in untrusted inputs.

If it's just simple arithmetic, I'd use a custom parser (there are tons of examples out in the wild)... And using parser generators (flex/bison, antlr, etc.) is a skill that is useful and easily forgotten, so it could be a good chance to refresh or learn it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I indeed read some about what you can do with `eval()`. Pretty frightening :D
But I use this for quick prototyping (later on I'll write a C++ reader/parser for the xml file). Plus it inly runs in a closed network, not connected to the Internet !

But I agree with you, it is not a good idea to keep it in final code.

Comment: yeah, for prototyping is fine :)... but be warned, it's so convenient that you risk to leave it forever! XD (it happened to me :p)

Comment: Haha I know too much how risky it is, programers are lazy :D
But people will read the code after me, they would not let it go this way (and that's for the best)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `parser` module:

```
import parser, token, re

def hexify(ast):
    if not isinstance(ast, list):
        return ast
    if ast[0] in (token.NAME, token.NUMBER) and re.match('[0-9a-fA-F]+$', ast[1]):
        return [token.NUMBER, '0x' + ast[1]]
    return map(hexify, ast)

def hexified_eval(expr, *args):
    ast = parser.sequence2st(hexify(parser.expr(expr).tolist()))
    return eval(ast.compile(), *args)

>>> hexified_eval('id*10 + BABE', {'id':0xcafe})
567466
```

This is somewhat cleaner than a regex solution in that it only attempts to replace tokens that have been positively identified as either names or numbers (and look like hex numbers). It also correctly handles more general python expressions such as `id*10 + len('BABE')` (it won't replace `'BABE'` with `'0xBABE'`).

OTOH, the regex solution is simpler and might cover all the cases you need to deal with anyway.

Comment: Nice solution, I like it! As I am only prototyping and working on very basic expressions I keep it simple'n'stupid, but this solutions seems to avoid a few problems